# Expand Multiple Lookup field with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph

How can I Expand a Multiple Lookup field with Microsoft Graph.

I need to get all fields from a multiple lookup field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my testing, you could use V1.0 to get lookup addition filed.

For example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteid/lists/dc0935d2-8cda-4bf2-b896-bb43e39bfbdb/items/2?expand=fields
```

Return value:

```
"MultiLookup": [
            {
                "LookupId": 6,
                "LookupValue": "a"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 7,
                "LookupValue": "b"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 8,
                "LookupValue": "ccc"
            }
        ],
        "Sponsor": [
            {
                "LookupId": 10,
                "LookupValue": "Lee",
                "Email": "Lee@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        ],
        "MultiLookup_x003a_Created": [
            {
                "LookupId": 6,
                "LookupValue": "2017-10-19T03:14:50Z"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 7,
                "LookupValue": "2017-10-19T03:17:25Z"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 8,
                "LookupValue": "2017-10-19T05:14:24Z"
            }
        ]
```

You could try to specify the return fields also.

```
?expand=fields($select=Title,MultiLookup,MultiLookup_x003a_Created)
```

Update:

field setting
[image]

Endpoint

```
/items/2?expand=fields($select=Title,MultiLookup,MultiLookup_x003a_MyNumber)
```

Return value

```
"fields": {
        "@odata.etag": "\"81e83b50-db18-47b0-b594-75795c403ee0,3\"",
        "Title": "test1",
        "MultiLookup": [
            {
                "LookupId": 6,
                "LookupValue": "a"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 7,
                "LookupValue": "b"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 8,
                "LookupValue": "ccc"
            }
        ],
        "MultiLookup_x003a_MyNumber": [
            {
                "LookupId": 6,
                "LookupValue": "20.0000000000000"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 7,
                "LookupValue": "21.0000000000000"
            },
            {
                "LookupId": 8,
                "LookupValue": "22.0000000000000"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I tried It, but the result is this: "Cargo": [
{
"LookupId": 3,
"LookupValue": "Quality"
}
], I need to get all fields of "Cargo", but this only gets "LookupId and LookupValue", I need to get the other fields of the other list as well: "Cargo": [
{
"LookupId": 3,
"LookupValue": "Quality",
"Code": "COD_01"
}
],

Comment: Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I would also like to point out that the Graph V1 API 
currently limits the characters for internal fields name to 32. I have not found any official documentation on the behavior but for lookup fields with length greater than 32, just truncate the extra characters.